# How to add "rel" attributes to all external links throughout the website?

Tags: 8, views, theming, hooks

I'm trying to add attributes for external links such as the `rel="noopener noreferrer"` for all the external links where `target="_blank"`. I've tried using modules such as the [noreferrer](https://www.drupal.org/project/noreferrer) and [sel](https://www.drupal.org/project/sel), but neither affect the links in my views.

How can I add `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to all links globally where `target="_blank"`?

Comment: As for affecting links in Views, it depends on how the links are configured in Views.  Are these links from a URL field being displayed?  Or links from a page display being shown embedded in Views?  Or links in custom text in the header/footer?

Comment: Also, the most popular module for this is [Extlink](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink).

Comment: Globally like also all links inside body text fields?

Answer (score 2):

By implementing [hook_link_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.9.x) in either a custom module or your theme.

The code (untested) would be similar to:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_link_alter().
 */
function MODULE/THEME_link_alter(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['options']['attributes']['target']) && $variables['options']['attributes']['target'] == '_blank') {
    $variables['options']['attributes']['rel'] = 'noopener noreferrer';
  }
}
```

Comment: This would add to the attribute even if already set to `noopener noreferrer`. The [Noopener Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/noopener_filter) module does it like above, but adds `if (empty($variables['options']['attributes']['rel']) || !in_array('noopener', $variables['options']['attributes']['rel'], TRUE)) {`. It also has it as an array, not a string. Like `$variables['options']['attributes']['rel'][] = 'noopener';`